# Задача на логику

Tags: логика, задание-на-собеседовании

Вот столкнулся с таким заданием на собеседовании. Лично я не разобрался, что тут к чему, и интересно было бы всё таки услышать ответ.

> Мастеру дали восемь цепей по 6 звеньев в каждой. Его попросили
>   соединить их в одну непрерывную цепь. Он выполнил просьбу, при этом он
>   разъединил и обратно соединил всего 6 звеньев. Как ему это удалось?

Comment: Полностью разобрал одну цепь и соединил остальные с помощью её элементов? (догадка за 10 секунд)

Comment: @andreymal Логично. Быстро вы сообразили)

Comment: Перенёс в ответы тогда)

Comment: Справедливости ради, ответ быстро нагугливается — http://znanija.com/task/1402555 .

Comment: Это же, скорее, задача на сообразительность, а не на логику (думаю, стоит поменять заголовок и метки).

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку. Разве такие вопросы можно задавать на SO?

Comment: Рубрика "логика" и "задачи на собеседования есть"? Так почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Полностью разобрал одну цепь и соединил остальные с помощью её элементов? (догадка за 10 секунд)
(из моего комментария)